# Teradata SQL data partition

Tags: sql, teradata

```
ID  ID1 Name
111 11  A
111 11  AA
222 12  B
222 13  C
```

I have a above table and I want the result as below.

```
ID  ID1 Name
111 11  A
111 11  AA
222 12  B
```

The basic idea is that when ID and ID1 have same row values then it should be visible as it is and when the ID row values is same and ID1 row values are different  then it should chose the above one.

Comment: What would you get if all four of your rows had `ID` of `111`?

Comment: the logic is written in such a way that we won't be getting four rows..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches your result and description, returning all rows with the lowest `ID1` per `ID`:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
QUALIFY
   RANK()
   OVER (PARTITION BY ID
         ORDER BY ID1) = 1
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Yup, should be `ORDER BY ID1`, fixed.